# Highcharts Navigator Zoom Dynamically

Tags: highcharts

By default, the chart zoom changes as long you release one of the handlers from the navigator.

Is there a way to make the chart zoom change as the handler is being moved by being held with left click instead of waiting for the left click to be released??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Christopher Vradis, In this basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/58ja429y/ the navigator seems to work in the described way. Could you specify your question?

Comment: That's exactly what i want but it is not working for me..

Comment: Could you create an example with a non-working version?